# Durable functions activity not accepting Uri parameter

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I'm using Azure Durable function and I see Activity parameter of type Uri throws exception "Cannot convert input parameter 'url' to type 'System.Uri' from type 'System.String'."

```
    [Function("OrchestratorAsync")]
    public async Task<string> OrchestratorAsync([OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("https://test/sample.txt");
        var result = await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("ActivityAsync", uri);
        return result;
    }

    [Function("ActivityAsync")]
    public async Task<string> ActivityAsync([ActivityTrigger] Uri url)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(url);
       return "result";
    }
```

"Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.10.0"

"Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.0.0"

"Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.7.0"

Dot-net Isolated 7.0

Answer (score 0):

The Custom Type conversion tries to parse the input as JSON and into the required type. It should work if you pass the input as a JSON object and use a Custom Class instead.

Or you could take the input as a string, and create a local object to parse it into a `Uri` object.